# SSRS - Multiple data points in single map location

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I want to display data of 5 operators (say A,B,C,D & E) and the revenue each operator has generated across the globe on a SSRS Map. I marked each operator against a specific color and vary the size of the marker(bubble) depicting the revenue received from the operator in that location. The problem is SSRS displays only one data point at a given location. I want to display all the operators that operate out of that particular location.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you share the query used to get the list of revenue per operator per location?

Comment: select operator, country,sum(revenue) from tablename group by operator,country